# How to get values from another table for concatenated array items?

Tags: php, mysql

Table 1: Name of Brothers Bloom
Note: The multiple values from column "ExFlames" is concatenated by the pipe symbol.

```
-------------------
ID   :   ExFlames
-------------------
1    :   1 | 3 | 4
2    :   2 | 3 | 4
3    :   3 | 4 | 5
```

Table 2: Name of Girls

```
-------------------
ID   :   Names
-------------------
1 :   Lucinda
2 :   Katy
3 :   Yoshimi
4 :   Rosebud
5 :   That Escort in Vegas
```

How can I output the values in PHP if I want this information?

ExFlames of Bloom Brother 1: Lucinda, Yoshimi, Rosebud

Comment: Why not use an N:M table when representing a many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT ExFlames from X;"
```

query it in php and put the result in an array $entries.

Then loop through them and query the other table.

```
for ($entries as $e) {
  $flames = explode($e, ' | ');
  for ($flames as $flame) {
    $query = 'SELECT Names from Y WHERE ID = ' . $flame . ';';
    …
```

Adapt to your code; table names, varnames etc.

For security you could also `intval()` the ID, and use prepared statements.